# What is default admin password for windows nodepool in AKS created through terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

I created the secondary windows node pool in my aks cluster, but since the `windows_profile` was optional in terraform, so I missed adding it back then.

I got to know that default user name is `azureuser`

But I am unable to find the default password.
How should I figure out this password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the password with command:

```
az aks update -g myResourceGroup -n myAKSCluster --windows-admin-password $WINDOWS_ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

Reference: [How do I change the administrator password for Windows Server nodes on my cluster?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-faq?tabs=azure-cli#how-do-i-change-the-administrator-password-for-windows-server-nodes-on-my-cluster)

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do that, there is no way to look it up, what you could do: is set it and update the cluster and the node pool afterwards.

Comment: Yes I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

So I looked in multiple places to be able to retrieve the password, but was unable to.
The only option left was to reset the password through the virtual machine scale set(VMSS) and then scale the node pool down and up back to original count so as new version of nodes come up.